# pfsense with 4 WAN IP and outgoing NAT

Tags: virtual-machines, nat, bridge, pfsense

I have a pfsense with a single wan ip, i want to assign multiple wan ip's. The pfsense machine is located on a vm machine with the other servers i wish to NAT forward. I want to give each server a wan ip address. The servers are all connected to the firewall with a internal virtual network interface. Can someone can help me on how to configure pfsense to NAT correctly.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the additional IPs as [IP Alias Virtual IPs](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/What_are_Virtual_IP_Addresses%3F#IP_Alias). Then configure 1:1 NAT to ensure that traffic to/from each of your servers is mapped properly.

Comment: Just to make sure, Interface = WAN for ip aliases and also NAT interface? If so, that doesnt seem to be letting traffic flow

Comment: Yes, the VIPs should be on your WAN interface. Then you'll need to create 1:1 NAT rules and the requisite firewall rules as well to allow traffic to flow.

Comment: Still unable to get it working http://i.imgur.com/3bgzFic.png So i created the VIP, then added the 1:1 for WAN and then created the firewall rule: IPv4 TCP *(source) *(port) 74.77.0.3 *(gateway) none